# 16.04 wont suspend when lid is closed

Tags: suspend, power-management

I have a HP Pavilion x360 I was able to get suspend and hibernation to work however it only works my the menu. When I close my lid it it just turns off the display.  It seems that any option I select in power management does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the machine to keep playing or running when you close the lid, then make sure that you set "When the lid is closed" to "Do nothing" both when your machine is on battery power and when it is plugged in.

Comment: What I am saying is I want the laptop to sleep when I close my lid but the power management gui does nothing. Currently when I close my screen the screen turns off but the system stays running. I do know that the sleep and hibernation works as I upgraded the kernel to fix the hibernation feature. When I select these from the menu it will sleep. Simply I need to set the screen close to put the machine in to sleep. The gui does not work.

Comment: Where is the field ""When the lid is closed" in Settings?  EDIT: Oops, sorry, never mind, found it under Settings->Power